# NFS transfer delay

Tags: debian, nfs, mount, debian-jessie, fstab

I adopt a bunch of webserver with a NFS storage behind the setup from an administrator who left our company.
The setup consists of eight webservers and one NFS storage server which work together.

The NFS storage server is mounted in the /etc/fstab of every webserver with the following paramters:

```
nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,hard,intr,ac,actimeo=600,sharecache,nordirplus,noacl,noatime,nodiratime 0 0
```

Each of the webserver runs Debian Jessie (3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Our customer often upload files with FTP over any of the Web-VMs to the NFS-Storage. 
He told us that it takes up to five mintues for some web vm to display the uploaded file completely. Some of the VMs display the uploaded file immediately other like I said after five minutes.

So I just wanted to ask if this is a normal behavior? Our other administrators think that there could be some other traffic which encumber the upload process and cause this delay. Maybe traffic which could be caused by apache which is also using the NFS mount points of the Web-VMs.

Otherwise I wanted to ask if the transfer parametes mentioned above are the problem.

It's hard to figure out which "leverage" I should shift also because the logs aren't really siginificant.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably related to your setting of `actimeo`. Reducing this from the current setting (10 minutes) is likely to speed up the visibility of changes (but at the expense of more NFS traffic and possibly higher latency for requests.